# Getting AuthenticationError.OAUTH_TOKEN_INVALID from google adwords API

Tags: google-ads-api

I have managed to generate developer_token, oauth client_id, oauth client_secret and oauth refresh_token, using the steps described [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/first-api-call), and I've set their values in the googleads.yaml.
I did not set any value to client_customer_id, because of an issue in the UI (opened [a thread](https://support.google.com/google-ads/thread/46366139?hl=en) with google adwords product team).
However, when I reached [this step](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/first-api-call#make_your_first_api_call), I got AuthenticationError.OAUTH_TOKEN_INVALID.
I'm using python 3.7, googleads 23.0.1 and code samples from [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/releases).

The code I'm running:

```
client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage(f'{os.getcwd()}/oauth/googleads.test.yaml')
# Initialize appropriate service.
campaign_service = client.GetService('CampaignService', version='v201809')

# Construct selector and get all campaigns.
offset = 0
selector = {
    'fields': ['Id', 'Name', 'Status'],
    'paging': {
        'startIndex': str(offset),
        'numberResults': str(PAGE_SIZE)
    }
}

more_pages = True
while more_pages:
    page = campaign_service.get(selector) # this is the line which raises the exception
```

Any suggestions?

Highly appreciate your help,
Tal

Comment: I have found Google's [OAuth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) to be a helpful tool in diagnosing OAuth2 issues. Make sure to supply your own client ID and secret by adjusting the settings (cogwheel icon on the top right).

Comment: Thanks @dorian, I've set my own client ID and secret in the OAuth playground, then it was also required to list the URL https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground in the Authorized redirect URIs (in developers console>project>Credentials>OAuth 2.0 client Ids). Unfortunately this setting exists only for web application, whereas google adwords test account requires a desktop app (or other app, in previous versions). I will use this cool tool in the future. Thanks.

Comment: You can still use the playground to try and exchange the `refresh_token` from your `googleads.yaml` for a new access token to see if that step works.

Comment: thanks @dorian, tried that, it works. 
The attempt to run an adwords api call using [this code](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/examples/adwords/v201809/basic_operations/get_campaigns.py) however, still results with AuthenticationError.OAUTH_TOKEN_INVALID

Comment: One additional thing to diagnose OAuth issues is Google's access token endpoint. You can do `curl https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=<YOURTOKEN>` to get some details (scope, client ID) of your access token.

Comment: Will do that, thanks @dorian